# HTML email template renders formula field as null. Formula references encrypted field(s)

Tags: email-template, shield-encryption

**Given**

- Cross-object formula field `My_Identifier__c` on Case: `Asset__r.My_Identifier__c`
- where `Asset.My_Identifier__c` is a text field, *Shield-encrypted*
- HTML email template that looks like:

  `Here is the identifier:{!Case.My_Identifier__c}<<`

**When**

- Email template rendered (using Send test and Verify Merge Fields) using a Case that references an Asset with a non-null value in `Asset.My_Identifier__c`

**Then**

- Template renders as `Here is the identifier:<<` ❗ *No merge field populated* ❗

**How do I fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As anyone using Shield encryption knows, there are all sorts of considerations documented here:

- [General Shield Platform Encryption Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_considerations_general.htm&type=5)
- [Considerations for Using Deterministic Encryption](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_deterministic_considerations.htm&type=5)
- [Use Encrypted Data in Formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_formulas.htm&type=5)

None of these are relevant

The workaround was surprising:

- Create a new custom formula field on Case called `My_Identifier_Clone__c`. *Copy-paste the exact same formula* as in `Case.My_Identifier__c`.
- Change the references to the formula field in the Email Template to be `{!Case.My_Identifier_Clone__c}`
- Retest - email renders correctly

I suspect I could also have deleted the original formula field `Case.My_Identifier__c` and add back but this would be problematic to deploy through a Devops pipeline without two steps

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- Original troubleshooting involved changing the encryption settings and re-syncing all the records in a sandbox. This had no affect on the original issue.
- We also confirmed that this was not a permission or sharing issues by logging in as multiple users with different settings.
- In a metadata comparison the new and old field are exactly identical. The original field was created a few years ago, but everything else is the same.

Comment: this is not an answer but rather a comment on @cropredy answer